# sscanf not detecting the right numbers

Tags: c, project

I'm having a hard time using sscanf to scan hour and minutes from a list. Below is a small snip of the list.

```
1704 86 2:30p 5:50p Daily
1711 17 10:40a 2:15p 5
1712 86 3:10p 6:30p 1
1731 48 6:25a 9:30a 156
1732 100 10:15a 1:30p Daily
1733 6 2:15p 3:39p Daily
```

I've tried this, but it keeps getting me segmentation Fault.(I'm putting this information into structures).

```
 for(i=0;i<check_enter;i++){
    sscanf(all_flights[i],
    "%d %d %d:%d%c %d:%d%c %s",
    &all_flights_divid[i].flight_number,
    &all_flights_divid[i].route_id,
    &all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_hour,
    &all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_minute,
    &all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_format,
    &all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_minute,
    &all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_minute,
    &all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_format,
    &all_flights_divid[i].frequency);

    printf("%d ",all_flights_divid[i].flight_number);
    printf("%d ",all_flights_divid[i].route_id);
    printf("%d ",all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_hour);
    printf("%d ",all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_minute);
    printf("%c ",all_flights_divid[i].departure_time_format);
    printf("%d ",all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_hour);
    printf("%d ",all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_minute);
    printf("%c ",all_flights_divid[i].arrival_time_format);
    printf("%s\n",all_flights_divid[i].frequency);
  }
```

This is how I declared it.

```
struct all_flights{
  int flight_number;
  int route_id;
  int departure_time_hour;
  int departure_time_minute;
  char departure_time_format;
  int arrival_time_hour;
  int arrival_time_minute;
  char arrival_time_format;
  char frequency[10];
};
struct all_flights all_flights_divid[3000];
```

These are the results I get

```
1704 86 2 30 p 0 50 p Daily
1711 17 10 40 a 0 15 p 5
1712 86 3 10 p 0 30 p 1
1731 48 6 25 a 0 30 a 156
1732 100 10 15 a 0 30 p Daily
1733 6 2 15 p 0 39 p Daily
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small mistake, that might be the problem:

this:

```
&all_flights_divid[1].flight_number,
```

should be:

```
&all_flights_divid[i].flight_number,
//                 ^
```

Edit:

Also, you read `arrival_time_minute` twice, and not reading `arrival_time_hour` at all. Fix it and it should be OK.

Comment: But now I'm getting a wired results. The time for arrival is still showing up as 0.

Comment: You are changing both source and output in the question, which makes all answers invalid. Please, if you still have a problem, add an edited code AFTER the original.

Comment: @Learning C: would you *please* check the relevant lines. I can't believe you don't see the problem.

Comment: Oh sorry guys. I didn't know. Been trying to write this code all day and I think my mind is not so alert any more. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the results seem to be fine, except the first field.

Now if you check your code..

```
&all_flights_divid[1]
```

fix it with

```
&all_flights_divid[i]
```